# How do I get the id of a particular record in database using NeDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, nedb

I have a record in database like:

```
   {"Name":"moon","Email":"night","User":"sun","Password":"earth","_id":"kpOBxczJlr2R5S68"}
```

How can I extract the id of this record and store it in a variable?

Comment: It would be easier to know what you're trying to do if you included some code example and told us what you have tried so far, what did you expect and what did you actually get (e.g. error messages).

Answer (score 2):

The id of the object is in the `_id` property, right in your example - in this case it's `"kpOBxczJlr2R5S68"`.

When you have the object in a variable called `object` then you can get the id with `object._id` - if I understand correctly what you're asking for because it's not very clear. This is not specific to any particular database, this is just how accessing object properties in JavaScript work.

Comment: var result={
      User: req.query.username,
      Password: req.query.password,
    }

This is my object, so should I write like result._id??

Comment: @Aarathi.V.B I don't understand what you meant to say by your comment. All I can tell is that you should never post usernames and passwords as query parameters, which you seem to do in that line of code.

Comment: @Aarathi.V.B Since you updated the comment above I can only add that If your object consists of only User and Password properties (unlike the object that you posted in the question) then of course you cannot access an _id property, since it doesn't have it.

Comment: So how do I access it without including in an object and directly from database?

Comment: @Aarathi.V.B I'm not sure what you're asking for. Do you want to find a user in the database by the username and then get the id? If so then first find the document and then get the id in the object that you get from the database. See the documentation https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#finding-documents